# Obj-C: Create Array From String Where items are in <>

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arrays

I am trying to parse a String to an Array each item is between <> for example `<this is column 1><this is column 2>` etc....

Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How about checking back and probably accept an answer or post follow up questions...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *input =@"<one><two><three>";
NSString *strippedInput = [input stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString: @">" withString: @""]; //strips all > from input string
NSArray *array = [strippedInput componentsSeperatedByString:@"<"];
```

Note that [array objectAtIndex:0] will be an empty string ("") an this doesn't work of course, if one of the "actual" string contain < or >

Answer (score 2):

Something to demonstrate:

```
NSString *string = @"<this is column 1><this is column 2>";
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];

NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];

NSString *temp;

while ([scanner isAtEnd] == NO)
{
    // Disregard the result of the scanner because it returns NO if the
    //  "up to" string is the first one it encounters.
    // You should still have this in case there are other characters
    //  between the right and left angle brackets.
    (void) [scanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:NULL];

    // Scan the left angle bracket to move the scanner location past it.
    (void) [scanner scanString:@"<" intoString:NULL];

    // Attempt to get the string.
    BOOL success = [scanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&temp];

    // Scan the right angle bracket to move the scanner location past it.
    (void) [scanner scanString:@">" intoString:NULL];

    if (success == YES)
    {
        [array addObject:temp];
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@", array);
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach might be to use either *componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet* or *componentsSeparatedByString* from NSString.

```
NSString *test = @"<one> <two> <three>";

NSArray *array1 = [test componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];

NSArray *array2 = [test componentsSeparatedByString:@"<"];
```

You'll need to do some cleaning up afterward, either trimming in the case of **array2** or removing white-space strings in the case of **array1**